# What does this line in Lang's "Algebra" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Lang's "Algebra" says the following:

> Let $S$ be a set. A mapping $S\times S\to S$ is sometimes called a law of composition (of $S$ into itself).

I always thought $S\times S\to S$ implied a binary operation on two elements of $S$, and $S$ being closed on that binary operation.

I also thought the word "composition" belonged to the world of **mappings**.

I don't see how a binary operation can be called a mapping.

EDIT: I must confess I have come across such a usage of the term "composition" before, but could never quite get the motivation behind it. Really hoping for an elaborate answer to shed light on this issue; something that I am sure confuses other autodidacts out there too.

Comment: Take $S =$ set of all mappings from $X$ to $X$. Does that help ?

Comment: @DiffeoR How is that supposed to clarify anything?

Comment: Don't get discouraged by the used terminology. Operations, mappings, compositions, operators, relations, morphisms  pfff... On this stuff you need to develop an attitude of acceptance if you want to survive in mathematics.

Comment: I was looking for the motivation behind treating elements as mappings. In general. Across branches of mathematics. Thanks

Comment: @algebraically_speaking I was just trying to illustrate the notion you know is a special case of this definition. Where the binary operation is $\circ$.

Comment: @drhab- True. But still maybe a small historical explanation or something of the sort would be nice. Why did we start treating elements as mappings? Surely that is not intuitive. And there must be a strong reason for doing anything non-intuitive.

Comment: @DiffeoR But that is not the case. You at least need $X = Y$ for that, and even then the map is a specific one, not just any map for this to be the usual composition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Thanks, edited, have to be careful next time !

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : What do you mean by "the map is a specific one" ?

Comment: @DiffeoR I mean that there are many maps form $S\times S$ to $S$ even when $S$ is as you suggest. Only one of those maps is the usual composition of functions.

Comment: It's Bourbaki language, I believe; instead of “operation” they talked about “law of composition”

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Thats precisely what I mean, composition of functions is an example of the above.

Comment: @DiffeoR Yes, but you never specified that. You only mentioned what one might have as $S$, which is not sufficient.

Comment: @egreg- Any motivation for Bourbaki to do so, other than maybe deliberately obfuscating concepts for aspiring mathematicians?

Answer (score 4):

A mapping from $S \times S$ to $S$ constructs a new element of $S$ by combining two given elements of $S$. So, for example, addition is a mapping $(a,b) \mapsto a+b$ that combines two elements to construct their sum, and multiplication combines two elements to construct their product.

And "composition" is just another word for "combining/constructing". In fact, in the original Latin, "compose" literally means "put together".

This is somewhat different from the "composition" that combines a function $f$ and a function $g$ to give their composition $f \circ g(x) = f\big(g(x)\big)$.  Maybe that's the source of your puzzlement.

In one particular case, composition of functions fits into the general framework I outlined above. If we let $S$ be the set of mappings from some set $X$ to itself, then the function composition operation $(f,g) \mapsto f \circ g$ is a binary operation on $S$. So, in other words, it's a "law of composition" on $S$. But I don't think this is very significant. I think the term "law of composition" is related to general "combining/constructing", not to the specific operation of composing mappings.

Regarding your other point: a binary operation definitely **is** a mapping. Specificially, a binary operation on a set $S$ is a mapping from $S \times S$ to $S$. See the examples of addition and multiplication above.

Comment: @bubba- I am not entirely convinced, as even category theory treats elements in objects as mappings. I don't think this is just a case of using the English word "composition" in different contexts.

Comment: Well, I'm convinced that Lang had the concept of combining/constructing (and nothing more) in mind when he wrote "composition", as explained in the first two paragrpahs of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase “law of composition” is a direct translation from the French *loi de composition* (usually also *interne* is added). See [Bourbaki, Éléments de Mathématique](http://books.google.it/books?id=4OnuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22loi%20de%20composition%22%20bourbaki&dq=%22loi%20de%20composition%22%20bourbaki&hl=it&sa=X&ei=Ta0MU6z0IIH_ywOS14DoCA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAg).

It's just a name and has nothing to do, in general, with function composition. Indeed, Lang says that *sometimes* a map $S\times S\to S$ is called a law of composition, probably aware of the fact that this locution is not very used in English speaking countries. It used to be frequent also in Italian text, under the influence of Bourbakism.

A binary operation is just a map (or mapping, if you prefer): to any (ordered) pair of elements in a set $S$ it associates an element of $S$. So it's best treated as a map (mapping, function, application, representation are also used), without introducing new concepts that aren't useful.

Answer (score 0):

The first groups that were studied are symmetry groups, like
$$
S_n = \{\, \varphi: [n]\to[n] \,\mid\, \text{$\varphi$ bijective}\,\},\quad
\text{where $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$}
$$
or the symmetry groups of geometric objects like polyhedra. In all of these, the elements actually are self-maps on some set and the group *composition* is the actual composition of these maps as maps.

These examples motivate why we sometimes call the operation in a group a *composition*.

Answer (score 0):

Associativity is often considered one of the most fundamental axioms in abstract algebra for a binary operation $S \times S \to S$, and it is well known that a set of functions under the binary operation of composition will automatically satisfy associativity.

Conversely, for a fixed $x \in S$, if we denote the function $t \mapsto x \cdot t$ by $L_x: S \to S$, then associativity can be restated as $L_{xy} = L_x \circ L_y$. Thus we see that the axiom of associativity is precisely the statement that, up to renaming, the binary operation *is* given by composition of functions on some set. So in the context of an associative binary operation, the term "law of composition" really does make sense.